# function toggleDisplay only displaying after two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it so when a button is clicked the contents of a div are changed but currently when I click the button it takes two clicks for it to happen. The page seems to refresh after 1 click so it seems that there's some problem here.

```html
<script>
    function toggleDisplay (toBlock, toNone) {
        document.getElementById(toBlock).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById(toNone).style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
    
<form method="get" id="1" onclick="toggleDisplay('OptIn', '1')" action="#">
    <h2>HEADLINE</h2>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click To Change Content">
    </div>
</form>
        
<div id="OptIn" style="display:none;">
    <h2>HEADLINE</h2>
    <div>
        FORM HERE
    </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: Clicking the submit input submits the FORM, not clear what are you expecting here?!

Comment: Changing the code to a snippet, nothing happens. Any idea what problem this code have?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<form method="get" id="1" onclick="toggleDisplay('OptIn', '1'); return false;" action="#">
```

and I guess you want to close the last div tag

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you're using a form and a submit button to change the `dom`? If not, the below would be better suited to your needs. If you need the form for something, we may need to know more to help:

```js
function toggleDisplay (toBlock, toNone) {
document.getElementById(toBlock).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(toNone).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div id="1" >
<h2>HEADLINE</h2>
<div>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Click To Change Content" onclick="toggleDisplay('OptIn', '1')">
</div>
</div>

<div id="OptIn" style="display:none;">
<h2>HEADLINE</h2>
<div>
FORM HERE
</div>
<div>
```

**Or with jQuery:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function(){
   $('.switch').toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch" >
<h2>HEADLINE</h2>
<div>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Click To Change Content" id="btn">
</div>
</div>

<div class="switch" style="display:none;">
<h2>HEADLINE</h2>
<div>
FORM HERE
</div>
<div>
```